# How can get the first name last name and id from this JSON in Java like to use Gson google json library

Tags: java, json

**I'm new to this java and Gson (google JSON).
this is the JSON data i.m getting from server.it have array and object.
I have to De-serialize by google library (Gson)**

```
{
   "d":{
      "results":[
         {
            "__metadata":{
               "id":"employeeHRSet('00005011')",
               "uri":employeeHRSet('00005011')",
               "type":"SRV.employeeHR"
            },
            "Gender":"M",
            "ImFname":"",
            "ProfilePic":"user_image.png",
            "ImLname":"",
            "ImPernr":"00000000",
            "ImSuper":"",
            "ImUname":"",
            "ExOk":"",
            "Perno":"00005011",
            "CompCode":"1000001013",
            "Name":"Nishan Thevathosan",
            "LastName":"Thevathosan",
            "LastName2":"Nishan",
            "Firstname":"Nishan",
            "Userid":"GEES02",
            "Email":"NISHAN@gamail.COM",
            "Celno":"",
            "Isexecutive":"Y",
            "Designation":"80000000"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

**I need to get Firstname ,LastName ,Email ,Userid from this JSON data. 
I'm in middle of a work i got struck in this please.
I have try some think like this but it didn't work.**

```
  JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(RESTRespArr).getAsJsonObject();
    System.out.println("jsonObject working");
    System.out.println(jsonObject.getAsString());
    JsonElement d = jsonObject.get("d");
    System.out.println("d working");
    System.out.println(d.getAsString());
    sonElement results = ((JsonObject) d).get("results");
    System.out.println("results working");
    System.out.println(results.getAsString());    
    System.out.println(((JsonObject) results).get("LastName").getAsString());
```

Comment: Take into account that "results" is not a JsonElement, it is most likely an array of JsonElements, this means that before you use the get("LastName") you must pick the position of the array of where you will look

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's worked for me.

```
final JsonElement lastName = results.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("LastName");
```

results is `JsonArray` of `JsonObjects`, you cant cast `JsonObject`. So get first element of array and cast it to `JsonObject` with `getAsJsonObject` method. And get which field do you need.

In detail:

if `JSON` any value in curlybrackets `{ ... }` , this is `jsonObject` . If values are in `[ ... ]`, this is `JsonArray`. Also you can get which one is object or array, and get it relevant fields from this.

Comment: mister or mam @ drowny Please send me how can i select object inside object. Is it correct. 'String json = RESTRespArr;
     JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
     JsonObject jsonObject = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(json);JsonElement d = jsonObject.getAsJsonObject().get("d");JsonElement results = d.getAsJsonObject().get("results");'

Comment: yes you can get like your said. But if you are not sure about JsonElement is JsonObject or JsonArray, you should check with `if(d.isJsonObject())` before casting.

Comment: Thank you so much for your kind help sir

Answer (score -1):

FIRST：

Your JSON data's format is incorrect on the seventh line:

modify `<"uri":employeeHRSet('00005011')",>` to `<"uri":"employeeHRSet('00005011')",>`

SECOND：

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(RESTRespArr).getAsJsonObject();

        System.out.println("jsonObject working");
        System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());

        JsonElement d = jsonObject.get("d");
        System.out.println("d working");
        System.out.println(d.toString());

        JsonElement results = ((JsonObject) d).get("results");
        System.out.println("results working");

        System.out.println(results.toString());

        System.out.println(results.getAsJsonArray().get(0).getAsJsonObject().get("LastName"));
```